# Remote debug with VSCode to VirtualBox Linux gives: Remote Debugging: close dlv connection

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, virtualbox, remote-debugging, dlv

I am trying to do simple remote debug from Windows VSCode to VirtualBox with a simple Go app. All ports are open in the port forward VBox config on nat.

[image]

From the VCCode it is configured like this:

```
 {
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Connect to server",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "attach",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "/home/xxx/go_test/",
            "cwd" : "${workspaceFolder}",
            "port": 3000,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "trace": "verbose",
            "asRoot": true,
            "apiVersion":1
        }
    ]
}
```

And in the Linux server like this:

```
xxx@xxx:~/go_test$ dlv debug /home/xxx/go_test/main.go --headless --listen=:3000  --log
API server listening at: [::]:3000
2023-11-14T16:09:40Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2023-11-14T16:09:40Z info layer=debugger launching process with args: [./__debug_bin3166801926]
2023-11-14T16:09:40Z debug layer=debugger Adding target 1336 "/home/xxx/go_test/__debug_bin3166801926"
2023-11-14T16:10:55Z debug layer=debugger continuing
2023-11-14T16:10:55Z debug layer=debugger ContinueOnce
2023-11-14T16:10:55Z debug layer=debugger continuing
2023-11-14T16:10:55Z debug layer=debugger detaching
```

vscode-go-debug.txt :

```
2023-11-14, 16:08:35.879 UTC
[16:08:35.879 UTC] From client: initialize({"clientID":"vscode","clientName":"Visual Studio Code","adapterID":"go","pathFormat":"path","linesStartAt1":true,"columnsStartAt1":true,"supportsVariableType":true,"supportsVariablePaging":true,"supportsRunInTerminalRequest":true,"locale":"en","supportsProgressReporting":true,"supportsInvalidatedEvent":true,"supportsMemoryReferences":true,"supportsArgsCanBeInterpretedByShell":true,"supportsMemoryEvent":true,"supportsStartDebuggingRequest":true})
[16:08:35.879 UTC] InitializeRequest
[16:08:35.879 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":1,"command":"initialize","success":true,"body":{"supportsConditionalBreakpoints":true,"supportsConfigurationDoneRequest":true,"supportsSetVariable":true}}
[16:08:35.880 UTC] InitializeResponse
[16:08:35.880 UTC] From client: attach({"name":"Connect to server","type":"go","request":"attach","mode":"remote","remotePath":"/home/xxx/go_test/","cwd":"C:\\dev\\my\\go_apps\\go_remote_debug_test","port":3000,"host":"127.0.0.1","trace":"verbose","asRoot":true,"apiVersion":1,"__configurationTarget":6,"packagePathToGoModPathMap":{"c:\\dev\\my\\go_apps\\go_remote_debug_test":"c:\\dev\\my\\go_apps\\go_remote_debug_test"},"debugAdapter":"legacy","showRegisters":false,"showGlobalVariables":false,"substitutePath":[],"showLog":false,"logOutput":"debugger","dlvFlags":[],"hideSystemGoroutines":false,"dlvLoadConfig":{"followPointers":true,"maxVariableRecurse":1,"maxStringLen":64,"maxArrayValues":64,"maxStructFields":-1},"dlvToolPath":"})
[16:08:35.880 UTC] AttachRequest
[16:08:35.880 UTC] Start remote debugging: connecting 127.0.0.1:3000
[16:08:36.213 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"initialized"}
[16:08:36.214 UTC] InitializeEvent
[16:08:36.214 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":2,"command":"attach","success":true}
[16:08:36.218 UTC] From client: configurationDone(undefined)
[16:08:36.218 UTC] ConfigurationDoneRequest
[16:08:36.221 UTC] Changing DebugState from Halted to Running
[16:08:36.222 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":3,"command":"configurationDone","success":true}
[16:08:36.222 UTC] ConfigurationDoneResponse {"seq":21,"type":"response","request_seq":3,"command":"configurationDone","success":true}
[16:08:36.229 UTC] continue state {"Pid":1336,"TargetCommandLine":"","Running":false,"Recording":false,"CoreDumping":false,"Threads":null,"NextInProgress":false,"WatchOutOfScope":null,"exited":true,"exitStatus":0,"When":""}
[16:08:36.230 UTC] handleReenterDebug(breakpoint).
[16:08:36.230 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"terminated"}
[16:08:36.230 UTC] TerminatedEvent
[16:08:36.248 UTC] From client: threads(undefined)
[16:08:36.248 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":4,"command":"threads","success":true,"body":{"threads":[]}}
[16:08:36.250 UTC] From client: disconnect({"restart":false})
[16:08:36.250 UTC] DisconnectRequest
[16:08:36.250 UTC] Issuing a continue command before closing Delve's connection as the debuggee is not running.
[16:08:36.250 UTC] Closing Delve.
[16:08:36.250 UTC] Remote Debugging: close dlv connection.
[16:08:36.251 UTC] DisconnectRequest to parent to shut down protocol server.
[16:08:36.251 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":5,"command":"disconnect","success":true}
[16:08:36.251 UTC] DisconnectResponse
[16:08:36.252 UTC] continue state {"Pid":1336,"TargetCommandLine":"","Running":false,"Recording":false,"CoreDumping":false,"Threads":null,"NextInProgress":false,"WatchOutOfScope":null,"exited":true,"exitStatus":0,"When":""}
[16:08:36.252 UTC] handleReenterDebug(breakpoint).
[16:08:36.252 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"terminated"}
[16:08:36.252 UTC] TerminatedEvent
[16:08:36.252 UTC] [Error] Socket connection to remote was closed
[16:08:36.253 UTC] Sending TerminatedEvent as delve is closed
[16:08:36.253 UTC] To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"terminated"}
```

Why can't it connect?

### Update

When connecting with dlv cli I can successfully connect to the server and set breakpoint and such

```
dlv connect 127.0.0.1:3000 --log --log-output=debugger,rpc,dap,stack
Type 'help' for list of commands.

(dlv) break main.go:8
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x78b0aa for main.main.func1() ./go_test/main.go:8
(dlv)
```

And this is on the remote server:

```
dlv debug /home/xxx/go_test/main.go --headless --listen=:3000  --log
API server listening at: [::]:3000
2023-11-15T05:57:02Z warning layer=rpc Listening for remote connections (connections are not authenticated nor encrypted)
2023-11-15T05:57:02Z info layer=debugger launching process with args: [./__debug_bin3481357464]
2023-11-15T05:57:03Z debug layer=debugger Adding target 1776 "/home/umen/go_test/__debug_bin3481357464"
2023-11-15T05:58:21Z info layer=debugger created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x78b0aa, Addrs:[]uint64{0x78b0aa}, AddrPid:[]int{1776}, File:"/home/umen/go_test/main.go", Line:8, FunctionName:"main.main.func1", ExprString:"", Cond:"", HitCond:"", HitCondPerG:false, Tracepoint:false, TraceReturn:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), WatchExpr:"", WatchType:0x0, VerboseDescr:[]string(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0, Disabled:false, UserData:interface {}(nil)}
```

So I guess it is somewhere in the VSCODE config.. but where ?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as expected.

You haven't set breakpoints in vs-code, so the debugee runs to the end and exits, and then dlv exits and the connection is closed.

What you need to do is to set a breakpoint in vs-code before starting debugging.

Other things to note:

1. According to [vscode-go debugging](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/debugging.md), `remotePath` is deprecated. Use `substitutePath` instead.
2. It's recommended to use the APIv2 as new features will only be made available through version 2. To use APIv2, start dlv with the `--api-version=2` flag and remove `"apiVersion":1` from `launch.json`.

References:

1. [JSON-RPC interface](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/api/json-rpc/README.md)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76469636/1369400